# Calling a Method at run time based on Its Name and Method

Tags: java

Working on a requirement where i need to call a class Method based on the name of the class and method being provided at runtime.

What are the different way by which i can achieve this (preferred one).One issue which i can see is that there can be multiple classes with same name so that can create a problem.

Any inputs how best this can be done will be much helpful for me

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have their fully qualified name (including the package)?

Comment: That was not somehow in initial request, but seems without which it  is not possible and can lead to potential conflicts and other strage behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the fully qualified class name with its package, which is unique for a ClassLoader.

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(packageAndClassName);
Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
```

You need to know the parameters types otherwise you can't give it sensible values when you call it.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs!! Agree have to use the fully qualified name.IN end i have to use refelction to call the method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you look for Reflection (see http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

Comment: Agree!! but problme was classes with same name.use of reflection is one step ahead

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use reflection: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

The pseudo code looks something like:

```
Get the Class object (Class.forName)
From the Class, lookup the Method you want (class.getDeclaredMethod)
Call the method (method.invoke)
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes have a qualified name you can use to prevent these "multiple classes with the same name". A Qualified name would be "com.example.ExampleClass" - a non-qualified name would be "ExampleClass".
You can get the qualified name with Class.getName();

As for the methods;
You can look up on reflection (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html). To call the function, use invoke on the java.lang.reflect.Method.